# Struggling to get JSON out in desired format with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "boxes" : {
        "box-1" : {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": false
        },
        "box-2" : {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": false
        },
        "box-3" : {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": true
        },
        "box-4" : {
            "what": "win",
            "opened": false
        },
        "box-5" : {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": true
        },
        "box-6" : {
            "what": "unknown",
            "opened": false
        },
        "box-7" : {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": true
        },
        "box-8" : {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": false
        }
    }
}
```

And when I load it in to my application (I'm using NodeJS):

```
var save = __dirname + '/save.json';
var saveData = fs.readFileSync(save, 'utf8');

if(saveData)
    reloadGame(saveData);
else
    askBoxes();

function reloadGame(saveData)
{

    saveData = JSON.parse(saveData);

    boxes = Object.keys(saveData.boxes).length;

    for(var i=0;i<=boxes;i++)
    {
        console.log(saveData.boxes[i]);
    }

}
```

See I'm having to use `Object.key`s to get the length.
And my console.log returns undefined inside my for loop.

I don't normally have to use the `Object.keys` to get the length of something inside a JSON file... And why doesn't my console.log work?

Feels like the JSON is incorrectly formatted. Perhaps I don't need the boxes key at all and can just have the boxes as an array instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveData.boxes` is **not** an array, and thus can not find the length of it directly with `length` property.

This is the reason you need to find the length using `object.keys`, if you dont want this, you can convert the list of boxes as an array.

Change your `json` to this:

```
{
    "boxes": [
        {   
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": false
        },
         {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": false
        },
        {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": true
        },
         {
            "what": "win",
            "opened": false
        },
         {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": true
        },
         {
            "what": "unknown",
            "opened": false
        },
         {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": true
        },
         {
            "what": "lose",
            "opened": false
        }
    ]
}
```

This way you will be able to access the boxes in the `for loop` in your code, and also you don't need the `Object.keys`.

**Note**: I removed the box numbers(which were keys before in your code), if you want them you can put them in array.

Comment: How would I reformat it to become an array? I tried but kept messing the JSON up...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access

```
saveData.boxes[0], saveData.boxes[1] and so on.
```

You need to access:

```
saveData.boxes["box-1"], saveData.boxes["box-2"] etc
```

You could use this:

```
boxes = Object.keys(saveData.boxes);

for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++)
{
    console.log(saveData.boxes[boxes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up converting the JSON to:

```
[{
    "box": "box-1",
    "what": "lose",
    "opened": false
},
{
    "box": "box-2",
    "what": "lose",
    "opened": false
},
{
    "box": "box-3",
    "what": "lose",
    "opened": true
},
{
    "box": "box-4",
    "what": "win",
    "opened": false
},
{
    "box": "box-5",
    "what": "lose",
    "opened": true
},
{
    "box": "box-6",
    "what": "unknown",
    "opened": false
},
{
    "box": "box-7",
    "what": "lose",
    "opened": true
},
{
    "box": "box-8",
    "what": "lose",
    "opened": false
}]
```

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Yeah I know :) I'd already created the file before I saw your comment regarding the box numbers.

Comment: In that case +1 buddy

Answer (score 1):

Cameron, not sure if you still have the problem but you could simply do

```
var tempBoxes = saveData.boxes;
for(var i in tempBoxes){
   console.log(tempBoxes[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use my modified reloadGame Function

```
function reloadGame(saveData)
{

    saveData = JSON.parse(saveData);

    boxes = Object.keys(saveData.boxes);
       for(var i=0;i<=Object.keys(saveData.boxes).length;i++)
    {
        console.log(saveData.boxes[boxes[i]]);
    }

}
```